# how to convert Decimal LatLng to DMS in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

I need to convert LatLng that I already have from map click in my `flutter` application to be `DMS`.
Here is an example

```
30.033333,31.233334 >> should be turned into >> 30° 1' 59.9988'' N,31° 14' 0.0024'' E
```

I've used a tool in some websites to do the above conversion, but I need to find out how it is being done to add the function in my flutter code

Comment: There are 60 minutes in a degree and 60 seconds in a minute.  30.033333 degrees is 30 degrees plus 0.033333 of a degree.  0.033333 of a degree is 0.033333 * 60 minutes = 1.99998 minutes.  1.99998 minutes is 1 minute plus 0.99998 of a minute.  0.99998 of a minute is 0.99998 * 60 seconds = 59.9988 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

As @jamesdlin's comment says , here is the function worked for this :

```dart
String convertLatLng(double decimal,bool isLat){
      String degree = "${decimal.toString().split(".")[0]}°";
      double minutesBeforeConversion =
          double.parse("0.${decimal.toString().split(".")[1]}");
      String minutes =
          "${(minutesBeforeConversion * 60).toString().split('.')[0]}'";
      double secondsBeforeConversion = double.parse(
          "0.${(minutesBeforeConversion * 60).toString().split('.')[1]}");
      String seconds =
          '${double.parse((secondsBeforeConversion * 60).toString()).toStringAsFixed(2)}" ';
      String dmsOutput =
          "$degree    $minutes    $seconds    ${isLat ? decimal > 0 ? 'N' : 'S' : decimal > 0 ? 'E' : 'w'}";
return dmsOutput ;
}
```

u give the function `decimal` as `lat` or `lng` then u give `true` or `false` for `isLat` .. this will define the `E` `N` `W` `S` at the end of your `dms` value